# GPUImage allocation not releasing with ARC enabled project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, gpuimage

I am taking multiple pictures continuously and processing them using GPUImage framework. I have a helper class essentially to perform the GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter. Here is what I do:

```
#import "ImageProcessor.h"

@interface ImageProcessor ()

@end

@implementation ImageProcessor

GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter *subFilter;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    subFilter = [[GPUImageSubtractBlendFilter alloc] init];
    return self;
}

-(UIImage*)flashSubtract:(UIImage*) image1 : (UIImage*) image2{
    UIImage *processedImage;
//    @autoreleasepool {

    //CAUSING MEMORY ISSUE
    GPUImagePicture *img1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    GPUImagePicture *img2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image2];
    //MEMORY ISSUE END

    [img1 addTarget:subFilter];
    [img2 addTarget:subFilter];

    [img1 processImage];
    [img2 processImage];
    [subFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    processedImage = [subFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

//    }

    //consider modifications to filter possibly?


    return processedImage;
}
```

Memory is continuously growing and doesn't deallocate even with ARC enabled. I debugged it and narrowed it down to these two allocations that are the heart of the cause:

```
 img1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:1]];
 img2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Am I missing anything here or is there anything I should do better to not continuously allocate GPUImagePicture varialbles?

Here is where the code originates from:

```
-(void)burstModeCapture : (AVCaptureConnection *) videoConnection : (int) i{//start capturing picture s rapidly and cache them in ram

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    NSLog(@"time entering: %d", i);


    [photoOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {

         if(error)
             NSLog(@"%s",[[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]);

         CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
         CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
         Byte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);
         size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);
         size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);
         size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
         NSData *dataForRawBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImageBytes length:bytesPerRow * CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)];
         // Do whatever with your bytes

         // create suitable color space
         CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

         //Create suitable context (suitable for camera output setting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
         CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImageBytes, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

         CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

         // release color space
         CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

         //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
         CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
         UIImage *FinalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage];
         [imagesArray addObject:FinalImage];//append image to array


         dispatch_group_leave(group);
     }];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//execute function recursively to shoot n photos
        //base case to stop shooting pictures
        shootCounter--;

        if (shootCounter <= 0) {
            [flash turnOffFlash];
            shootCounter = NUMSHOTS;
            UIImage *output = [self processImages]; //THIS IS WHERE MEMORY STARTS ACCUMULATING
            [self updateUIWithOutput:output];
            NSLog(@"Done shooting!");
        }
        else {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.1];
            [self burstModeCapture:videoConnection : shootCounter];
        }
    });


}
```

I run this function recursively twice to capture pairs of images. [imageProcessor flashSubtract] is where the problem exists.

Comment: Is there any reason `GPUImagePicture *img1` and `GPUImagePicture *img2` are not local variables in your `flashSubtract:` method? If you need them elsewhere you should define them as class properties. I'm not saying it will resolve your problem, but won't hurt for sure.

Comment: They initially were local variables, I tried making them globol thinking that this may resolve it. But nothing changed.

Comment: Your mutable array will also hold references to the objects, so if you keep adding your objects to it and it grows in size, you would be using more and more memory. Btw passing mutable arrays as arguments is not a good practice, it's much safer to pass a nonmutable copy.

Comment: I only store two values in that array and i perform `[imagesArray removeAllObjects]` after every pair of picture is done processing. I changed the code to taking two copies of the images and working with those, it still continuously increases in memory usage after those two lines of allocation of GPUImagePicture.

Comment: So why don't make a method that uses 2 arguments instead of using `NSMutableArray` ?

Comment: Yes I switched it to using two arguments, nothing changed memory problem still exists. I'll update the question with my new code.

Comment: Can you provide some code showcasing where UIImages originate?

Comment: I updated it for you to check out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `CGContextRelease(newContext);` after your `CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);` line. This might cause your memory leak.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work unfortunately. When i stepped through the code, its the two lines i mentioned earlier that suddenly increased the memory usage.

Comment: I'm passing in the images like this:

`UIImage *processedImage = [imageProcessor flashSubtract:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:1] : [imagesArray objectAtIndex:0]];`
Could this potentially be a referencing problem?

Comment: It shouldn't cause the problem, but using a temp variable is a super quick thing to check. Worth trying.

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it out! I ran the build analyzer and realized that I don't release my CGImageRef object (newImage). You were correct about the general area for memory leak!

Comment: Another bug bites the dust ;-) Congrats and happy coding